# How to get the data in the controller with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an HTML table with some fields, and each row has a link to save the data. Can I redirect to the controller, but do not know how to get the data in the controller to save.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>#</th>  
        </tr>
      </thead>

        <tr>
          <td>Gleydson</td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="value"></td> 
          <td>
            <select class="form-control">
                  <option value="tipo">Type 1</option>
                  <option value="tipo">Type 2</option>
                  <option value="tipo">Type 3</option>
            </select>     
          </td>
          <td> <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Register'),'/payments/register/'.$user['User']['id'],array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Emília</td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="value"></td>   
          <td>
            <select class="form-control">
                  <option value="tipo">Type 1</option>
                  <option value="tipo">Type 2</option>
                  <option value="tipo">Type 3</option>
            </select>     
          </td>
          <td> <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Register'),'/payments/register/'.$user['User']['id'],array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Form Helper to build your form. Check out the docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

If you're submitting to a different controller you may have to use "action" or "url" within the ->create method. But the issue you're experiencing is that the post data isn't being submitted, mainly because you're using "link" and you're not posting or creating a form correctly.

Make sure to use debug($this->data); within the correct method of the controller to check the data submission.

The method you're using just produces a link (lorem)
[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink)

It may be worth going through the getting started guides to get a better idea of how Cake works. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html

If you're looking to then redirect the user after the form submission you can use code within your controller to redirect them to the correct location.

**Your view:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Register'); ?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>#</th>  
    </tr>
  </thead>

    <tr>
      <td>Gleydson</td>
      <td><?php echo $this->Html->input('value', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'div' => false)); ?></td> 
      <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->select('types', array('Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3'), array('class' => 'form-control'));  ?>
      </td>
      <td> <?php echo $this->Html->submit(__('Register'),array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Emília</td>
      <td><?php echo $this->Html->input('value2', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'div' => false)); ?></td>   
      <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->select('types2', array('Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3'), array('class' => 'form-control'));  ?>
      </td>
      <td> <?php echo $this->Html->submit(__('Register'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Your Controller:
Also see:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html
and 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

```
public function update() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Register->validates()) {
            return $this->redirect(
               array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'thanks')
            );
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('Unable to validate')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

More info on saving your data:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: nice answer. very detailed. @gleydson you should try this.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think the OP needs to create a form for every row and not a single form containing all the rows. In fact it seems that he wants to save a row at a time, otherwise what's the deal of having many submit buttons

Comment: @arilia you might be right, but the question's description isn't clear.